# Household income by ZIP+4

Tags: data-request, data.gov, economics, income

Does anyone know of a source to find household income by ZIP+4? I have found IRS information on each five digit ZIP, but was hoping to find more precise information by ZIP+4.

Comment: I don't know if such a dataset exists that defines ZIP9 by geographic areas that would also tabulate household income. Aside from the sampling issues would also be concerns for privacy. Could you tell us why such data at such a geographic level is desired? Maybe you could settle for an alternative form of geography.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that ZIP codes are not geographies (see [this other answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4379/18)).

Also, as Kotebiya notes in a comment, there aren't pseudo-geographies for ZIP+4 and if there were, they would probably represent too small a group of people to allow data sharing without concern for individual privacy.

There may be commercial services that approximate this level of detail, but I am extremely doubtful that any public agency makes it available.

Comment: The US Census would not publicly provide household data at this level since a Zip5+4 could be a single person or business.

Comment: That's what I was getting at: "too small a group of people to allow data sharing without concern for individual privacy."